# Does You Tube allow app builders to use their service to host and play videos from many users?

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

I am building an iPhone app that will let iPhone users upload videos and share them.  When we upload videos to our server, playback is choppy.  Can we route these uploaded videos to You Tube, and play them back through You Tube (without the iPhone user having to create an individual account)?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload videos to YouTube and play them back on an iOS device, but it is very strongly recommended that you require users to upload videos into their own YouTube accounts rather than storing them in some master account. The reason for this is explained at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community.html